# how to link to ssrs report from asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm having trouble linking to an ssrs report from my asp.net webpage.
the direct link is

server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fRig+Dashboard%2fRig+Status+Report

I also need to pass in two parameters which is FileTypeID and Date

Please help...

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://server/Reports"); // Report Server URL
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Rig Dashboard/Rig Status Report"; // Report Name
    ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
    ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = true;
```

ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
 The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Comment: Look into ReportViewer control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx

Comment: naw I want a direct link

Comment: What trouble are you having? Errors, 404, permissions?

Comment: just cannot find the server.. i'm not sure the format on how to properly think this

Answer (score 1):

Your doing it wrong.  You are trying to call the 'landing page' : /Reports NOT THE SERVICE: /ReportServer.  Yuriy gave you a good place to get started.  I can give you an example of how I do it in some local code I use in WPF calling a Windows Form(blech!):

```
private void ResetReportViewer(ProcessingMode mode)
        {
            this.reportViewer.Clear();
            this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer.ProcessingMode = mode;
        }

        private void ReportViewerRemote_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResetReportViewer(ProcessingMode.Remote);
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://server/ReportServer");
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Folder/ReportName";

            reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void ReportViewerRemoteWithCred_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResetReportViewer(ProcessingMode.Remote);
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://server/ReportServer");
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Folder/ReportName";

            DataSourceCredentials dsCrendtials = new DataSourceCredentials();
            dsCrendtials.Name = "DataSource1";
            dsCrendtials.UserId = "DedicatedUser";
            dsCrendtials.Password = "P@ssword(jk)";
            reportViewer.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new DataSourceCredentials[] { dsCrendtials });

            reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        }
```

Comment: thanks I figured that out just before you posted.. but I like your source credentials code thanks